# STDistance function call performance degrade with SQL Spatial Index enabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, spatial, spatial-index

I use `STDistance` and a `geometry` column to discover rows with a certain distance to a specific point. The issue is that when I'm using a spatial index the query performance degrades dramatically (for 1kk rows it's executed for about 10 sec). My `t-sql` query:

```
declare @location geography;
set @location = xxx;

select count(*) 
from MyTable
where GpsLocation.STDistance(@location) < 50000
```

I tried to recreate the index with different tessellation schemes, grid systems, density, etc. Nothing helps.... except when I deleted the index the query start to perform instantaneously. So I ended up deleting the spatial indexes at all but I'm really confused why I should use them.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you looking at the query plan (both with and without the spatial index)? Also, while they should be equivalent (i.e. your query should use the spatial index efficiently), I typically create a buffer of the prescribed distance around the object that I'm trying to search for (using `STBuffer()`) and then using `STIntersects()` with that to see if it's within that boundary.

Comment: how many rows is found? 50000 seems very big...

Comment: 300000 returned by the query above.